# using tfilelist or tfiledelimited how can i iterate through a list of columnA, column B combination and store in tjava to use for tdbinput

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv, talend

I have a talend job that i am trying to read the columns from the csv file sequentially row by row for each combination (if possible trying to collect unique combination) of COLUMN A & COLUMN B to get the values and store in tjava (context variables to reuse and query the tdbinput)

CSV in the below format:
[image]

OPTION 1:
My job design looks like this:
tfilelist-Iterate-->tjava -->tdbinput

Tjava:

````
```
 `int n = 600; // The line number
      int i=0;
      String line="";
      int linenumber=0;
```

`try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))))`
`{`

`while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && linenumber< n )`  
`{`
`if(iteration == 0)`
`{`
`iteration++;`  
`continue;`
`}`
`String[] tokens = line.split(",");`

```
   for(String token : tokens)
                {
                    //Print all tokens
                    System.out.println(token);
                }
```

`context.columnA=tokens[0];`
`context.columnB=tokens[1];`

```
     linenumber++; 
 }
```

```
```
````

When i try to use the context.columnA in the other component tdbinput it will has the last overwritten value and not the iterated value for each row sequence

tdinput:
select * from test where testcol='"+context.columnA+"';
RESULT IS NULL because context.columnA value is empty from tjava

OPTION 2:I tried using :
tfileinputdelimited--main-->tjavarow

tjavarow:

```
context.columnA = input_row.columnA ;
context.columnB= input_row.columnB;
```

but this approach doesnt help me to directly pass the inputs into tdbinput(to query the database using select)

So i would like to know if there is a way to iterate from tfileinputdelimited---iterate-->tjava??? but unable to store the schema results between the component.

Updated job design for approach2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krHXJ.png)

Anyone please advise a way to perform either using java code to handle it or adjust the talend components to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using your second approch :

`tfileinputdelimited ->tJavaRow-main1->tFlowtoIterate->tdbInput`

You can use the global Variable in tdbInput as below `((String)globalMap.get("main1.lot"))`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,i tried using tflowtoiterate as well but when it gets over to tdbinput the values of columnA & columnB become null when stored in the global or context variables.I have added the image of the revised job design in the question as it wont let me add images to the comment section

Comment: What is the SQL query you used

Comment: tflowtoiterate (using the default key value selection) and iterate---> tdbinput

Here is the select used inside it


"SELECT   df.cond1, df.cond2, df.cond3
FROM test df
LEFT JOIN sample dd ON df.module=dd.module  
LEFT JOIN trial dl ON df.logic=dl.logic WHERE df.columnA='"+((String)globalMap.get("row2.columnA"))+"' and df.columnB='"+((String)globalMap.get("row2.columnB"))+"'
and  file_date between  to_date('"+context.startDate+"' ,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  and to_date('"+context.endDate+"' ,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
order  by df.file_date desc"

Comment: try this to debug , tfileinputdelimited ->tJavaRow-main1->tFlowtoIterate->tJava (here print  ((String)globalMap.get("row2.columnA")) )

Comment: desactivate tdbInput -> tLogRow and please verify your output schema in tJavaRow

Comment: Yes i tried that exactly just now to see the values are getting carried over but it seems like they are showing up as NULL

System.out.println("columnA: "+((String)globalMap.get("row2.columnA")));



System.out.println("columnB: "+((String)globalMap.get("row2.columnB")));

Comment: Try the button  generate code  in tJavaRow and synchronise also

Comment: Still null:
Tjavarow:
output_row.columnA= input_row.columnA;
output_row.columnB= input_row.columnB;

tflowiterate:
default key value

tjava:
System.out.println("columnA: "+((String)globalMap.get("row2.columnA"))); System.out.println("columnB: "+((String)globalMap.get("row2.columnB")))

tfileinputdelim--row1(main)-->tjavarow--row2(main-->tflowtoiterate--iterate-->tjava

Comment: Okey try this tfileinput -> thashoutput

Comment: On subjobok thashinput (same schema thashoutput) tflowtoiterate -> tjava

Comment: Thank you so much,you're simple awesome ,it worked with thashoutput and i was able to iterate for every record combination of column A &  column B from the file and query the db to retrieve the results sequentially in an iterated way.Appreciate the support & assistance

Comment: Appreciate it , good luck

Comment: Hi @Amine Ben Khelifa ,if you can take a look at my below post and provide some suggestions to implement this feature,it would be really helpful and appreciate your inputs whenever you can.Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74272029/using-tftpput-to-fetch-a-single-file-amongst-50000-files-from-the-source-local-d