# Using tFTPput to fetch a single file amongst 50000 files from the source local directory to upload to FTP

Tags: java, ftp, find, expression, talend

Is there a way to get exactly one file based on the exact match in filename from the list of 50000 files from the source local directory and upload it to FTP remote directory?

JOB:

```
context.dir="\\Test\filter\sample\MATCHES\ABC123";

context.filename="ABC_XYZ_Test_123.csv"

context.destinationdir="\Upload\"
```

I was able to use global variables to extract the `context.dir && context.filename` and store in it. Now the `context.dir` has 50000 files and I need to filter or look for the exact match for one specific filename namely ABC_XYZ_Test_123.csv from the local folder `\\\\Test\\filter\\sample\\MATCHES\\ABC123`

Correspondingly upload the file to FTP site:

`tjava--row1-->tftpput`

**tFTPput** has the below attributes configured:

```
LOCAL DIRECTORY:context.dir+"\\" 
Remote directory:context.destinationdir
Filemask:context.filename
```

If I try executing the above job it takes forever to complete a single upload (either its upload to match & retrieve the file from the source local folder since there are 50000 files OR the time taken to upload each file worth 100's of MB of data is long)

Unsure what is causing the delay, is there any way to finetune the job to make it work faster & efficiently?

Comment: You can do this : tfileList -> tjava(dummy just print the names and filepaths) ->  thashouput

Comment: Onsubjok ok thashinput (get the same schema of thashoutput) -> tfilterrow( equals context.filename) -> tlogrow

Comment: Thanks for the response,again this is also taking long time to find/search based on the filename since the folder has around 50k odd files in there
in my tfilelist i have the value for DIRECTORY as context.dir+"\\"
Filemask as context.filename

tfilelist-tjava-thashboutput
|
onsubjok
|
thashinput->tfilterrow-tlogrow

tfliterrow has  file_name(inputcolumn) equals context.filename(value)

Comment: Everytime i use filerow or direct upload from tftpput ,its taking a long time to search and match the specific file from the folder since its time consuming to find a exact match among 50k files?

Comment: could you show me your job design ?

Comment: Thanks Amine,i was able to get them into staging directory first and then do the upload,it worked well!